# Javascript replace using key mappings and regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I am attempting to create a function that encodes special characters in a url. I looked into the npm package: urlencode but it doesn't encode all characters for some reason (such as parenthesis). I start by replacing the percent symbol so there is no interference with the rest of the code replacements. I made a mapObj array to feed into a regex and for some reason all of these characters are not getting replaced. The parenthesis and the periods especially. Any idea why?

```
const replaceSpecialChars = function (str) {
   
    str = str.replace('%', '%25')

    var mapObj = {
        "&":"%26", 
        "`":"%60", 
        "-":"%2D", 
        "|":"%7C", 
        ".":"%2E", 
        "(":"%28", 
        ")":"%29"
    };


    var re = new RegExp(Object.keys(mapObj).map(key => key.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, '\\$&')).join('|'));
    str = str.replace(re, function(matched){
        return mapObj[matched];
    });

}
```

Comment: . is any character and () is a capture group.

Comment: this isn't a global regex, so it only matches the first instance

Comment: Also, I'm not even sure why you're generating the regex by using a regex - surely, it's easier to just do `str.replace(/[-[\]{}()*+?.,\\^$|#\s]/gi, replacer)`

Comment: @VLAZ I remove the gi and made it just g. Is that was you mean?

Comment: @BlakeRivell the regex *you generate* and assign to the variable `re` is **not** global. It doesn't have the `g` flag.

Comment: @VLAZ I am generating the regex by using a regex to help escape REGEX specific chars such as / and ^

Comment: @VLAZ I see what you mean, I added , "gi" to that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have overcomplicated it a little bit, single `String#replace` is enough.

```js
var mapObj = {
  "&": "%26",
  "`": "%60",
  "-": "%2D",
  "|": "%7C",
  ".": "%2E",
  "(": "%28",
  ")": "%29"
};

const replaceSpecialChars = (str) => 
   str.replace(/./g, (m) => mapObj[m] ?? m);

console.log(replaceSpecialChars('&_-_(_)_.'));
```

Comment: thank you for this answer. Two questions: 1. Why did you use ' ' for the join instead of '|' and the reason I am doing regex within regex is to make sure the REGEX chars such as | and ^ would be escaped. Does yours account for that?

Comment: Problem will arise if the keys contain one of the few characters that can be a problem in a character class. Most notably `]`. I really don't see the reason to generate a regex dynamically here. Either write it once and that's it, so you know it's correct, or instead just do `str.replace(/./g, x => mapObj[x] ?? x)` and replace everything without having to worry "what regex actually matches the mappings I have".

Comment: @VLAZ Yeah, I guess its a good point, dynamic regex isnt really necessary here. Thanks.

Comment: @BlakeRivell the regex generated here puts everything in a character class `[]` - most symbols lose their special meaning in there, so there is no need to escape them. Except maybe a dash (unless at the beginning end), the ones shown here would not be interpreted as anything else than a literal.

Comment: @BlakeRivell Used empty string for join to get a string containing only characters as keys from `mapObj`. I have wrapped it with `[]` so the `|` isnt needed anymore. Anyways - dybamic regex creation isnt necessary.

Comment: @kinduser Alright, one last question.. Can I include the Percent replacement as long as it is at the beginning of the mappings or will it interfere?